# Writing Junit Test case for merging files in sftp server

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5, apache-commons-vfs

I am using `apache commons VFS` to connect to sftp server and write the content of files in `/input` directory into a single file in `/output` directory.The names of files in input directory is provided as a `List`. I am struggling to write `Junit`  test case for it.My intention is that once the code gets executed, I will compare the contents of file in `/input` against content of file in `/output`

```
public void exportFile(List<String> fileNamesList){
for (String file : fileNamesList){
            try(FileObject fileObject= //getsFileObject
                OutputStream fileOutputStream= fileObject.resolveFile("/output/"+"exportfile.txt").getContent().getOutputStream(true);
            )
                                            fileObject.resolveFile("/input/"+file).getContent().getInputStream().transferTo(fileOutputStream);
    
            }
            }
```

I want to write Junit test case for the above. The below is my setup for test case

```
            @BeforeAll
                  static void setUpSftpServer() throws IOException {
                System.out.println("inside setup ssh");
                sshd= SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
                    sshd.setPort(1234);
                    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider());
                    sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(AcceptAllPublickeyAuthenticator.INSTANCE);
                    sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Arrays.asList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
                    sshd.start();
            }
        
         @Test
            void exportFileTest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        
                System.out.println("Inside exportFile test");
                FileObject fileObject=getFileObject();
                when(sftpConfiguration.connect()).thenReturn(fileObject);
                myobject.exportFile(Arrays.asList("a.txt"));
               String actualContent=fileObject.resolveFile("/input/a.txt").getContentContent().getString("UTF-8");
 String expectedContent=fileObject.resolveFile("/output/exportFile.txt").getContentContent().getString("UTF-8");
                assertTrue(actualContent.equals(expectedContent));
        
        
            }
    static FileObject getFileObject() throws URISyntaxException, FileSystemException {
            String userInfo = "uname" + ":" + "pwd";
            SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder sftpConfigBuilder = SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance();
            FileSystemOptions options = new FileSystemOptions();
            IdentityProvider identityInfo = new IdentityInfo(new File("/fake/path/to/key"), "test".getBytes());
            sftpConfigBuilder.setIdentityProvider(options, identityInfo);
            URI uri=  new URI("sftp", userInfo, "127.0.0.1", Objects.requireNonNullElse(1234, -1), null, null, null);
           FileObject fileObject= VFS.getManager().resolveFile(uri.toString(),options);
           System.out.println("creating file object complete");
           fileObject.resolveFile("/input").createFolder(); //create a folder in the path
           fileObject.resolveFile("/output").createFolder(); 
           //code  to create a file called a.txt inside /input and write the string "abc" to the file
            return  fileObject;
        }
```

But I am getting an exception like below

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code "Could not get the user id of the current user (error code: -1)".
```

This exception I am getting at the line

FileObject fileObject= VFS.getManager().resolveFile(uri.toString(),options);

How do I write the unittest for this case correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the `SftpFileSystem` failing to run the command `id -u` which doesn't exist on some SSH connections such as Windows OpenSSH. It runs this command when attempting to detect the exec channel. Resolve this by adding the following SFTP configuration:

```
sftpConfigBuilder.setDisableDetectExecChannel(options, true);
```

See [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-vfs/blob/861711cc04c222372d940311d7ea9272a9983f97/commons-vfs2/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/sftp/SftpFileSystem.java#L98).